# numpy vectorization(accumulate variable)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a dataframe.
Witch contain a few columns. It's look like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | a | Nan |
| 2 | 11 | b | Nan |
| 3 | 12 | c | Nan |

So if I have 'b' in column C, I should do A+B.
In other cases A*B.
But with that I have variable that accumulate value(You will see code and it will be cleare).
So I write this code

```
z = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a = df['A']
    b = df['B']
    c = df['C']
    if c == 'b':
        d = a + b + z
        z = z + 2
    else:
        d = a*b
    df.at[i, 'D'] = d
```

But df.iterrows() is antipattern and I should avoid this string in my code.
Because if my data set increase it will be a problem
I have tried to use vectorization but I can't figure out how to accumulate.
Code look like this:

```
z = 0
con = (df['C'] == 'b',
      df['C'] != 'b')
choise = (
    (df['A'] + dfs['B'], z + 2),
    (df['A'] * dfs['B'], )
)

dfs['D'], z = np.select(con, choise)
```

Can someone help me with that? How to accumulate variable z?

Comment: No it is not counting how many times. The code is just counting value of (something).

Comment: Yes, sorry I noticed my mistake. A question about your sample code: `a`, `b`, and `c`, should be values coming from `row` instead of `df`? Is that a typo?

Comment: I don't understand you comment.  d should count on a and b in row.

Comment: I mean, `a = df['A']` does not make sense, because you're not even using the `row` variable from your loop. I think it should be `a = row["A"]`

Comment: Also, I think the only part that you can not vectorize is the value of `z`, which is like a rolling counter. The other operations can be vectorized though

Comment: I will be that person that questions the question... Are you sure that a df is the good data structure? Rows in a dataframe are supposed to be independent, while the existence of the accumulator variable in your code points to the opposite direction (because the order matters, hence the rows are not independent)

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. I should write row['A'] etc.

Comment: Well I  think data have a good structure(I hope). It is excel file. 
I simplified my code for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm puzzled as to what that first code block is supposed to be doing:

```
z = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a = df['A']
    b = df['B']
    c = df['C']
    if c == 'b':
        d = a + b + z
        z = z + 2
    else:
        d = a*b
    df.at[i, 'D'] = d
```

`i` and `rows` are the iteration variables, but you don't use `rows`, and only use `i` at the end to set something in the original `df`.

Do you understand what `iterrows` does (other than all it an "antipattern"):

Look at a small df:

```
In [168]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3), columns=['A','B','C'])
In [169]: df
Out[169]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
```

and do `iterrows` with a lots of prints:

```
In [170]: for i, row in df.iterrows():
     ...:     print('==========')
     ...:     print(i, type(row));print(row)
     ...:     a = df['A']
     ...:     print('a', type(a));print(a)
     ...: 
==========
0 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A    0
B    1
C    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    0
1    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
==========
1 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A    3
B    4
C    5
Name: 1, dtype: int64
a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    0
1    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

`rows` is a pandas Series (e.g. one column of a dataframe), with data from one row.  It's like it turn the row into a column. `df['A']` is also a Series, but one of the `df` columns.

That whole:

```
a = df['A']
b = df['B']
c = df['C']
if c == 'b':
    d = a + b + z
    z = z + 2
else:
    d = a*b
```

block of code is working with the columns of the frame - whole columns, not values from one row.  There's no point in repeating those calculations again and again in the loop.

`c` is a Series, so `if c=='b` with raise an error.  Using the `a` from my example:

The '==' test produces a Series
In [172]: a==3
Out[172]:
0    False
1     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

Using that Series in an `if` raises an `ambiguity` error.

```
In [173]: if a==3: print('yes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-173-1ccc6f02d1f6>", line 1, in <module>
    if a==3: print('yes')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So your use of `iterrows` is more than a "anti-pattern".  The code that uses is just plain wrong.  I gone into a lot of detail because I think you need more than "quick" answer.  You need to understand what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
z = 0
new_D = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.C == 'b':
        new_D.append(row.A + row.B + z)
        z += 2
    else:
        new_D.append(row.A * row.B)

df['D'] = new_D
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to quit loop in my code. But your answer really helped. I will try this later. But I think `itertuples()` more efficient than `itertuples()`